# Date Format in Dashboards

Tags: salesforce, apex

I am working on salesforce dashboards and i need to display date as january1 2020 instead of 01-01-2020.

Sample output

[image: Output should be like this]

But my date formats are coming like this

[image]

Can anyone suggest me what to do?

Comment: Your question says `i need to display date as january1 2020` but then the sample you've attached says `Q3 CY 2021`. That's now quite confusing that what do you actually want.

Comment: I need to display as Q3 CY 2021
Can you help me